# How do I access the property of an object in an array?

Tags: 7

I need to get the the "companyId" but am not sure of the syntax

[image]

Comment: Just an FYI, but with PHPStorm (I am guessing that is what that is) you can right click on anything and do "Copy Path" which would give you the path.

Answer (score 2):

It might be:

```
$invite_requests[20]->companyId
```

However, that's only if $companyId has been declared as a public variable. If it has not, there should be a method (function) of retrieving it. You'll need to find the file that contains the class ApigeeCompanyInvitationEntity, and look for a method there if this is the case.

Comment: You may want to search the `ApigeeCompanyInvitationEntity` class for `return $this->companyId;`

Comment: Good additional information, that gives something to search for.

Answer (score 0):

I should have been more specific but I was able to access and adjust the property in `$invitation` via a `foreach loop`

```
foreach ($invite_requests as $invitation) { 
         'do something here'}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just an FYI, but with PHPStorm (I am guessing that is what that is) you can right click on things in the debugger and do "Copy Path" which would give you the path. But I also think you would want to loop `$invite_requests` which would probably make your inner loop have:

```
$companyIds = [];

foreach ($invite_requests => $invitation) { 
  $companyIds[] = $invitation->companyId;
}
```

That only works if that property is public, what you are likely after is a getter method i.e. `getCompanyId()` for that object.

Either way, this question is more generic PHP than Drupal.

Use the IDE to inspect the class methods.